# How to specify data types during saveAsTable

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following two statements:

```
spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db1.tb1")
sdf_agg.write.saveAsTable("db1.tb1")
```

The reason is that I'm getting the following error message when im loading in the data and converting `to_Pandas()`

```
UserWarning: The conversion of DecimalType columns is inefficient and may take a long time.
```

Should these columns be altered to `double` and if so at which point?

- in my query like `select cast(column as float)`
- altering my table by changing the column types after it was created
- or completely disregard this error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure which are the Boolean column in your code , but before saving, you can cast a column like below

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
df = df.withColumn("id", F.col("id").cast(T.BooleanType()))
```